# Log Event ID to display time of first boot on a Windows Machine?

Tags: windows, powershell, logging, windows-event-log

Say I factory reset a machine, or just installed Windows on it.

Is there a way to use Get-WinEventLog to find a log message to indicate this is the first time since the installation of the OS that the machine booted?

I want to prove that I factory reset a machine and after reloading the software on it, that I am still getting the same result as before I factory reset it.

Comment: Please add more details about your use case, technology you want to use to detect this (PowerShell?) and what you're trying to achieve exactly. There might be more than one way to get what you want.

Comment: @JevgenijMartynenko Better?